# How to Process Nested struct with Array element in Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am using spark sql data processing for nested with array.

```
{
        "isActive": true,
        "sample": {
            "someitem": {
                "thesearecool": [{
                        "neat": "wow"
                    },
                    {
                        "neat": "tubular"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "coolcolors": [{
                    "color": "red",
                    "hex": "ff0000"
                },
                {
                    "color": "blue",
                    "hex": "0000ff"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

schema :

```
root
     |-- isActive: boolean (nullable = true)
     |-- sample: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- coolcolors: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- hex: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- someitem: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- thesearecool: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- neat: string (nullable = true)
```

code :

```
val nested1 = nested.withColumn("color_data", explode($"sample.coolcolors")).select("isActive","color_data.color","color_data.hex","sample.someitem.thesearecool.neat")
            val nested2 = nested.withColumn("thesearecool_data", explode($"sample.someitem.thesearecool")).select("thesearecool_data.neat")
```

sample output:

```
+--------+-----+------+--------------+
|isActive|color|hex   |neat          |
+--------+-----+------+--------------+
|true    |red  |ff0000|[wow, tubular]|
|true    |blue |0000ff|[wow, tubular]|
+--------+-----+------+--------------+

+-------+
|neat   |
+-------+
|wow    |
|tubular|
+-------+
```

we need to process data single result.

Comment: i don’t understand what is the question?

Comment: hi above the data i can process two different rdd data but i need to process single table.. like  one explode process one array of data and i need to process second array same rdd

Comment: nested.withColumn("color_data", explode($"sample.coolcolors")).select("isActive","color_data.color","color_data.hex","sample.someitem.thesearecool.neat")..... this is give one out put

Comment: nested.withColumn("thesearecool_data", explode($"sample.someitem.thesearecool")).select("thesearecool_data.neat"). this is give one output... i need to merge or single output of all the json nested with array data

Comment: can you please help us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode twice, and select what you want.

```
df.withColumn("coolcolors", explode($"sample.coolcolors"))
  .withColumn("thesearecool", explode($"sample.someitem.thesearecool"))
  .select("isActive", "coolcolors.color", "coolcolors.hex", "thesearecool.neat").show
```

Then,

```
+--------+-----+------+-------+
|isActive|color|   hex|   neat|
+--------+-----+------+-------+
|    true|  red|ff0000|    wow|
|    true|  red|ff0000|tubular|
|    true| blue|0000ff|    wow|
|    true| blue|0000ff|tubular|
+--------+-----+------+-------+
```